# Edit,Detail,Delete not Working in partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Partial View for Searching after search Record and i want to delete record when i click on delete then open new page and show message delete successfully but i want to show this message in the same page not new page

this is my Controller

```
  public string Delete(string id)


         { 

        oj.Delete(id);

        return "del Successfuly";

    }
```

Here is my view 
when i am click on delete link the open new page and show Successfully message 
bu i want to show message in the same page

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
 <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_fname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_lname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_dob)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_contact1)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_address1)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_cnic)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dept_id)
            </td>
            <td >

                <div   id="tdi">

  @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.emp_id }, new AjaxOptions
   {
       UpdateTargetId = "#tdi",
       HttpMethod = "Get",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
   })

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need install the jQuery AJAX Unobtrusive library:

If you don't have this libary in your project, don't works the ajax request, so, the link opened in another page.

Install:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

View:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```